# Compose Key combinations are wrong in KDE/QT apps

Tags: kubuntu, keyboard-layout, qt, kde4

On Kubuntu 12.04 LTS.

For some reason, Qt applications (Kate, Konsole, etc.) were loading the ISO8859-1 Compose key file, instead of UTF-8. Other applications (Chrome and Java apps, for example) were working correctly.

You can tell if this is happening by typing the following key combination:

<Compose_key> then <underscore> then <a>

If you get ā (an a with a macron), you're using the UTF-8 file. If you get ã (an a with a tilde), you're using the ISO8859-1 file.

The only way I figured out to fix the problem was to install qt4-qtconfig and change the "Default Input Method" to xim instead of ibus. It must be that ibus is looking in the wrong  spot for the Console file.

Hope this helps someone else (and I hope the Qt developers fix the problem for Qt5).

Comment: IBus does not heed .XCompose, it uses its own files. Please add an answer by yourself and accept your answer.

Comment: Where do the files IBus uses live?